# Red-Black Trees are arbitrarily defined to be left-leaning. How can I make it right-leaning?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

As the title says, red-black trees created using modified binary search trees have the arbitrary restriction that all red links are left-leaning. I've made a basic program for red black trees (java) and I'm curious how to change this, since it seems it would be simple but all the solutions elude me.

My code is close to the same as in this PDF:
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf

For example here's the treeRepair method in the left leaning version:

```
private TreeNode<Key, Value> treeRepair(TreeNode<Key, Value> node)
{
    if (isRed(node.right) && !isRed(node.left)) node = rotateLeft(node);
    if (isRed(node.left) && isRed(node.left.left)) node = rotateRight(node);
    if (isRed(node.left) && isRed(node.right)) flipColours(node);

    node.size = 1 + size(node.left) + size(node.right);

    return node; 
}
```

This works just fine. It runs at the end of every insertion and deletion.
Here's a modified "flipped" version which actually works some of the time.

```
private TreeNode<Key, Value> treeRepair(TreeNode<Key, Value> node)
{   
    if (isRed(node.left) && !isRed(node.right)) node = rotateRight(node);
    if (isRed(node.right) && isRed(node.right.right)) node = rotateLeft(node);  
    if (isRed(node.left) && isRed(node.right)) flipColours(node);

    node.size = 1 + size(node.left) + size(node.right);

    return node; 
}
```

I have a strong hunch it has to do with the delete method, (it often works with large groups of insertions but then a single deletion causes problems such as multiple red links in a row.) but flipping lefts and rights in that method inevitably produces NPEs.

If this is a bad kind of question to ask on this site, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have any real reason for this? Or just for its own sake? I have to say, I can't think of any case where you would really need this

Comment: I'm trying to get a better grasp on how red-black trees actually work, I'm pretty novice.

Comment: If you switch every `left` to `right` and vice versa and keep the order you are using now, I don't see how it *couldn't* work, since it's totally symmetrical

Comment: Or you just swap the order relation. Then the tree is still left-leaning but the values will be ordered in reverse

Comment: You mean every left and right in the whole program? That was one of the first things I tried, along with switching every "deleteMax" with "deleteMin" or whatever. Surprisingly, the program functioned exactly the same. (That is to say, left-leaning.)

Comment: @user3443103 That is to be expected, but the small values will be on the right side then.

Comment: What @NiklasB. is saying, is that the internal representation is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @Cruncher That's not what I'm saying. There is probably a reason why OP wants it to be right- intead of left-leaning, for example because he/she wants to have small values nearer to the root. What I'm saying is that I don't understand why the simplest possible approach wouldn't work (switching the order relation around)